# Sort a CSV column by date with text header and numerical column

Tags: bash, sorting, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Order,Item,Date
387-0293,chips,04/26/2016
133-4454,soda,04/25/2016
284-9989,beer,04/27/2016
```

The amount of orders changes daily.

How can I get the third column to sort by date?

I've tried a bunch of different sort combos, here are some things I tried that I thought would have worked:

```
cat test.csv | sort -t, -k3 > sorted.csv
cat test.csv | sort -u -r > sorted.csv
cat test.csv | sort -n -k3 > sorted.csv
```

I'm not super knowledgable with bash, just been searching here and google for answers.

Answer (score 6):

You were quite close:

```
$ sort -t , -k 3.7n -k 3.1,3.2n -k 3.4,3.5n test.csv -o sorted.csv
Order,Item,Date
133-4454,soda,04/25/2016
387-0293,chips,04/26/2016
284-9989,beer,04/27/2016
```

The `-k` option takes up to two parameters where you can specify start and end of a sort field as a one-based string. `3.7n` is "from the 7th character of the 3rd field to the end of the line, numerically", `3.1,3.2n` is for "1st and 2nd character of the 3rd field, numerically" and so on.

The first sort field starts after the end of the third field in the first line, so it is empty, which gets sorted before the numbers.

Comment: perfect explanation. I put the exact same thing in my terminal but it's not sorting though, any idea why? Would version # on my system or a server make a difference? I'm using Mac terminal GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release.

Answer (score 0):

One way using GNU awk using the built-in mktime and PROCINFO:

```
awk -F, '
    BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"}
    NR==1 {print $0; next}
    {   
        split ($3, d, /[/]/); 
        time = mktime (d[3] " " d[1] " " d[2] " 00 00 00"); 
        sorted[time] = ((time in sorted) ? sorted[time] RS $0 : $0)
    } 
    END {for (key in sorted) print sorted[key]}
' file 
Order,Item,Date
133-4454,soda,04/25/2016
387-0293,chips,04/26/2016
284-9989,beer,04/27/2016
```